# TensorFlow: CovNet returning same output for all the examples

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have 200 images on a set, 100 identical squares and 100 identical circles. Images are 44x41 pixels and images are grayscale. I am trying to build a simple classifier to learn tensorflow.

The problem: the predictor vectors have always the same value regardless the input image.

Here's the code of my neural net:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import random as r
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from PIL import Image
%matplotlib inline  

#create pictures

for i in range(100):
    fig1 = plt.figure(frameon = False, figsize=(1,1), dpi=32)
    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    posx = 0.25
    posy = 0.25
    ax1.add_patch(
        patches.Rectangle(
            (posx,posy),   # (x,y)
            0.5,          # width
            0.5,          # height
        )
    )
    ax1.axis('off')

    fig1.savefig('rect' + str(i) + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')

for i in range(100):
    fig1 = plt.figure(frameon = False, figsize=(1,1), dpi=32)
    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    posx = 0.5
    posy = 0.5
    ax1.add_patch(
        patches.Circle(
            (posx,posy),   # (x,y)
            0.3,
        )
    )
    ax1.axis('off')

    fig1.savefig('circ' + str(i) + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')

# create vectors    

train_features = np.zeros((200,44,41,1))
train_labels = np.zeros((200,2))

for i in range(100):
    #get rect
    im = Image.open("rect" + str(i) + ".png")
    im = im.convert(mode = "L")
    xxx =list(im.getdata())
    imdata = np.reshape(xxx, (44,41,1))
    train_features[i] = imdata
    train_labels[i] = np.array([0,1])
    #get circle
    im = Image.open("circ" + str(i) + ".png")
    im = im.convert(mode = "L")
    xxx = list(im.getdata())
    imdata = np.reshape(xxx, (44,41,1))
    train_features[i+100] = imdata
    train_labels[i+100] = np.array([1,0])

tf.reset_default_graph()

features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,44,41, 1])
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,2])

weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3, 1, 16], stddev=0.1)) 
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(16))

weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3, 16, 64], stddev=0.1)) 
biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(64))

conv_layer = tf.nn.conv2d(features, weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
conv_layer_b = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_layer, biases)
conv_layer_relu = tf.nn.relu(conv_layer_b)
conv_layer_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv_layer_relu, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

conv_layer2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv_layer_pool, weights2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
conv_layer2_b = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_layer2, biases2)
conv_layer2_relu = tf.nn.relu(conv_layer2_b)
conv_layer2_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv_layer2_relu, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

#fully connected layer
weights_fc = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([44*41*64, 256], stddev=0.1))
biases_fc =  tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))
fc = tf.reshape(conv_layer2_pool, [-1, weights_fc.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
fc_logit = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc, weights_fc), biases_fc)
fc_relu = tf.nn.relu(fc_logit)
#fc_drop = tf.nn.dropout(fc_relu, 0.75)

# final layer

weights_out = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([256, 2], stddev=0.1))
biases_out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc_relu, weights_out), biases_out)   

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=out, labels=labels))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in range(100):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={
                features: train_features[:],
                labels: train_labels[:]})
    for i in range(200):
        outx = sess.run(out, feed_dict={
                features: [train_features[i]],
                labels: [train_labels[i]]})
        print(outx)
        print(train_labels[i])
        print('---')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to give the same name to two tensors. For example, you have `conv_layer` that is equal to `tf.nn.conv2d(features, weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')` then rewriten to `tf.nn.bias_add(conv_layer, biases)`, then once more then its another shape and then ....

Use this naming for example:

```py
conv_layer = tf.nn.conv2d(features, weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
conv_layer_b = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_layer, biases)
conv_layer_relu = tf.nn.relu(conv_layer_b)
conv_layer_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv_layer_relu, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

The algorithm learns one image at a time. Try to feed all the images in your set if your machine can handel it: `sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={features: train_features[:], labels: train_labels[:]})`. If not 100 images from both classes. Are the images shuffled or first come 100 circle and than 100 squares? Here can lie the error. You update your weights 100 times with only squares in the last loop.

Can I see the the complete program, with the part that you print the predicted vector? As a first stage I would take the dropout out; let it overfit. And then, maybe, use a smaller fc_layer (512 or 256), smaller learning rate (0.01), and I prefere `tf.get_variable('w1', shape=[3,3,1,16])` instead of `tf.Variable(...)`, initialize the biases with value 0.1.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reponse. I changed the naming to avoid giving the same name to two tensors but it didn"t solved the problem.

Comment: still doesn't work. i included the full code in the question

Comment: Sorry that didn't work! Try `imdata = np.reshape(xxx, (44,41))`. If it doesn't work, please give me one circle and one square image so I can try to run the program on my computer.